# Not able to use gsed and grep command on jenkins

Tags: bash, macos, jenkins

I made a script on OSX terminal which utilizes the gsed and grep commands. I tried running this on a jenkins job but it seems that these were incompatible in this unix environment. Here is an example of the code I'm trying to run:

```
line_formatted=$(gsed -r '/name="adhoc.display"/{s@(.*value=")([^"]*)(".*)@\1$R{\2.LABEL}\3@g;}' <<<"$line")
sed -i bak -e 's|'"${line}"'|'"${line_formatted}"'|g' $topicJRXML_source
adhoc_value=$(grep -oE '{[^/]+}' <<<"$line_formatted" | cut -c2- | rev | cut -c2- | rev)
```

I am able to assign my formatted lines I'm reading from a file into the variables `line_formatted` and `adhoc_value` on the OSX terminal but when these are run on jenkins it seems to fail with the error: `gsed: command not found`

I was wondering if there is a way to run these commands on jenkins, or if there is an equivalent way to express these lines on jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have the gsed command installed and in the PATH on the jenkins machine. Is the jenkins machine a linux box? You aren't running these commands in Jenkins. Jenkins runs the commands on the local machine in a shell.

Comment: I was looking more of an equivalent way to express these commands on a linux box. I'm not able to set up the "gsed" command because it would interfere with a server dependency that would completely break

Comment: sed and grep are standard on any linux installation I'm aware of. Not sure if you are doing something special with gsed that isn't in sed. You should be able to find plenty of information on how to convert from gsed to sed, but I bet they are mostly the same.

Comment: Ok sounds good, I managed to fix the sed part, been having trouble with grep. I was calling the grep command you see above against something like this:
`<property name="adhoc.display" value="$R{EXAMPLE.LABEL}"/>`
which would extract `EXAMPLE`, but instead it has been extracting this instead:
`<property name="adhoc.display" value="$R{EXAMPLE.LABEL`.
This command worked successfully on my OSX terminal but not working very well on linux shell

Comment: I think when using the -E option, `{` and `}` have special meaning. It can be used to give the number of times the previous thing should match. That may be part of the problem. What if you use a backslash before each of those things? But your pattern is saying to match anything that isn't a `/` followed by a `}`.  I think you would want something like: `'\{[^.]+'`. But I'm not completely sure what you are going for.

Comment: This worked! Weird that the curly braces didn't have the be escaped in the osx terminal. Thanks for the help